# Twitter follow Url

Tags: url, twitter, twitter-follow

Hitting the url `http://twitter.com/home?status=<status_msg>` takes us to the twitter login page and once logged in, the status is already filled in the input box, ready to be tweeted.

Is there a similar url for following somebody on twitter ?

something of the form `http://twitter.com/follow?user=<user_to be_followed>` so that when this url is hit, the user is taken to login page(if not authenticated), and after a successfull login, the logged in user becomes a follower of the user in the url.

Comment: I don't know, but it's probably a bad idea without asking the user first. It's better to just link to the profile and let the user follow it themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use OAuth.  That will direct the user to Twitter for authentication and to authorize your app to act on their behalf.  It will then give you a token that you can use to make API calls for that user.

It's not a terribly simple thing to implement and might be more trouble than it's worth for your situation, but the option is there.  Look for a library for your platform of choice, they exist for most languages.

Answer (score 14):

I got information from https://dev.twitter.com/docs/intents#follow-intent
and now you can use `https://twitter.com/intent/user?screen_name=<twitter_screen_name>`

Answer (score 7):

https://twitter.com/intent/follow?screen_name=[USERNAME]

in fact, there's a few 'intent', this one is particularly useful

https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=[TITLE]&url=[URL]

it is **much** better to use simple links like these for all sharing buttons than the buttons provided by the social sites which will multiply HTTP requests alarmingly.

Comment: this doesn't follow automatically the user, you still need to manually click `follow`

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's feasible, but not with a simple url -- you will need to POST data as directed in the [`friendships/create`](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-REST-API-Method:-friendships%C2%A0create) method of the [Twitter API](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-API-Documentation):

> Allows the authenticating users to
>   follow the user specified in the `ID`
>   parameter.  Returns the befriended
>   user in the requested format when
>   successful.  Returns a string
>   describing the failure condition when
>   unsuccessful. If you are already
>   friends with the user an `HTTP 403` will
>   be returned.

Comment: I dont want to ask the user for his/her username and password. I want the user to be authenticated by twitter itself. Looks like there is no available url to do that !

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a link like "follow us!". You can use the Twitter API to make a link that when clicked does the right POST call to the API, but there's no way to obtain a simple link like you asked.